# Не подключается к Google Play Services и не показывает рекламу AdMob

Tags: unity3d, google-play, admob, google-play-services

**Движок Unity.**

Может была у кого такая проблема, но с ней мучаюсь уже как 2 недели. До того как компилил (в internal) отдельные apk файлы было всё хорошо и показывалась реклама, и подключалось к GP. После по необходимости, чтобы уменьшить размер самого приложения, я начал компилить через gradle, расширение aab. Возникла первая проблема, мой пароль содержал символ "\", и из-за этого gradle ругался и не собирал проект. Пришлось писать в тех.поддержку, чтобы дали возможность поменять пароль для проекта. Ждали сообщение от них 3 дня (ни слова. Писал я им где-то 15 сентября и спустя месяц 16 октября, они мне ответили(но оно мне уже было не надо).). 
Решили создать новый проект, после 5 дней ожидания от тех.поддержки, ждали публикации 6 дней и залили туда приложение. Т.к в игровых сервисах мы уже и ачивки сделали, и таблицу достижения. Связали ещё одно приложение и всё.
После совсем случайно заметили, что нет рекламы, а то и вовсе подключение к GP. Ассет переустанавливал, в манифесте доступ к интернету прописан.

```
 PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.Authenticate((bool succes, string error) =>
        {
            if (succes) Debug.Log("Вход выполнен удачно");
            else Debug.Log("ERROR: Вход не выполнен! " + error);
        });
```

Данные строчки он и вовсе пропускает на телефоне (отдельно создавал объект текста и чтобы он туда хоть что-то выводил, вообще 0 реакции), на компе отображает что "Вход не выполнен", ну тут то оно понятно. В дебаг консоле рекламу так же отображает, что она загружена и будет тут отображена, на телефоне 0 реакции.
Кто-то сталкивался с таким? Или хотя бы в каком направлении данную ошибку исправлять? Множество вариантов перепробовал за 2 недели.

Comment: У меня была такая проблема, но связана была с принудительно выключенным подключением к сервисам гугла - во всяких китайцах такое в настройках есть.

Comment: Друг тоже тестил, у него тогда же началась данная проблема как и у меня :(

Comment: А что логи устройства говорят? Я использую mLogcat - там можно логики по тэгу Unity отфильтровать и посмотреть ошибки, если они есть - туда все `Debug.` выводятся